# Automate deploying Kafka on Kubernetes network

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm researching ways I can integrate Kafka into my micro service based Kubernetes architecture that I plan on hosting at some point. The current way I see to do this based on an article is linked [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-apache-kafka-with-kubernetes-9bd5caf7694f). But this will not work out for the one reason that I have to manually enter the NodePort IP I have been assigned while deploying the zookeeper service. What would be the best way to connect my Kafka and zookeeper Kubernetes services without manually entering the zookeeper's NodePort address? Or would the best approach be to not use Kubernetes at all for this?

Answer (score 1):

That blog is using `wurstmeister/*` images, which are not recommended to be used in Kubernetes if you want it to "just work"

Use a Helm Chart, or Operator such as https://strimzi.io for a simple deployment within k8s; otherwise, use a cloud hosted Kafka instead to more quickly get started.

Besides, the Zookeeper IP should never have been used. It should be `zookeeper-service.svc.cluster.local`. Refer [K8s DNS docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)

Answer (score 0):

There are few options for exposing and external access to kafka:

1. NodePorts
2. Ingresses
3. LoadBalancer
4. Route (openshift)

Also for automating this procedure, bitnami kafka do this automatically with and init container with kubectl image and a script that find nodeport service of each broker and config kafka external advertised listener to that.